# How to connect pandas data frame and dict?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to connect data frame and dict like this . the number of frames for each cell is different
,so the number of "0","1"and so on is different .Total number of cells 16.How can

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add code of your data frame and dictionary and lastly, where you are stuck. It is unclear what you are asking now

Answer (score 0):

To combine a pandas data frame with a dictionary, you can use the pandas.DataFrame.from_dict() function. This function takes a dictionary as input and returns a pandas data frame.

For example, you can create a dictionary with keys as column names and values as data for each column, and then pass this dictionary to the from_dict function to create a data frame:

import pandas as pd

data = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

print(df)